# Persistent file mark in vim

Tags: vim

I would like <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to (almost) always open `$MYVIMRC`. For instance, if I do <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, I would like it to revert back when I start a new Vim instance.  How would I go about setting this mark in `$MYVIMRC` file?

Oddly enough, adding `normal mV` to `MYVIMRC` sets a mark in `~/.viminfo` at `1  0`. o.O

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can set a mark to a specific file via .vimrc, however you can map a command to ``V` so that it opens your $MYVIMRC (won't retain the specific line though)

```
:nnoremap `V :e $MYVIMRC<CR>
```

Of course you can also pick another key sequence so you don't override the normal ``V` behaviour.

Comment: Agreed. I don't think marks are the right solution for this. See `:h last-position-jump` for a way to restore cursor position upon opening files.

Comment: @EtanReisner I already have `` `" `` in `$MYVIMRC` to open last position when restoring a file.

Comment: Does that work? I was under the impression that was too early to be of any use (the buffers haven't been loaded yet) also that only happens once whereas the last-position-jump autocmd happens on every opened file.

Comment: @EtanReisner what I have is the same thing at `:help last-position-jump`

Comment: Also `:help restore-cursor`

Answer (score 0):

The following is the best answer that I came up with.  I would be happy to accept any answer that is better or more complete (with implementation) than mine.

Have a script in `$MYVIMRC` that edits the `~/.viminfo` file, adding the appropriate line to the `#File Marks:` section:

```
'V  1  0  ~/.vimrc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are taking the problem from the wrong end. Instead of starting with a mean and trying to make it do what you want, start with what you want and work out a solution.

If what you want is to be able to open your vimrc quickly, you should use a mapping like

```
nnoremap ,v :e $MYVIMRC<CR>
```

Which will obviously never interfere with your ability to use file marks *and* doesn't require to mess with your viminfo.

---

To answer your other question:

```
nnoremap ,v :vs $MYVIMRC<CR>
```